# safari caching the html pages using jquery mobile and ZEND sessions

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-mobile, safari, browser-cache

Hi I have the following php code

```
 if($this->sess->loggedIn == 1){
      $this->_redirect("Queue/index");
 }
```

What I am doing here is checking that If user is logged in and presses the back button. I am sending him again to the main page. This is working on all browsers except safari, But safari performs all the server side code instead of redirect. re-direct also works if I refresh the page coz My session is set. I think safari loads the page from cache. Is there any way to sort this out. I am using jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following these two steps

1. Update the safari to latest version

add

```
<body onunload="">
```

this will prevent the browser from caching the pages